# Не может определить channel в discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, heroku

Я написал команду, которая ставит реакцию на сообщение и шлёт в отдельный канал сообщение.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

@client.command(name='Report', aliases=['отзыв'], description='логи')
    async def report(message):
        if message.message.content[10:] == '':
            await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Отзыв", 
            description='Сюда можно слать ваши пожелания к боту или жалобы на ошибки.',
            color=discord.Colour.blue()))
        else:
            await message.message.add_reaction('')
            message_content = str(message.message.content)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Инфа', description='_ _', colour=discord.Colour.red())
            embed.set_author(name=message.author.name, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name='Содержимое:', value=f'{message_content}', inline=False)
            channel = client.get_channel(821809754061013046)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Но почему-то мне выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
  await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
  await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
  raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'сhannel' is not defined
```

Что мне c этим делать?

Comment: Это весь traceback, или только последняя его часть? Обычно traceback должен указывать, на какой строке произошла ошибка, в вашем traceback'е указан только последний стек библиотеки

Comment: Мой traceback выдаёт строчку channel = client.get_channel(821809754061013046) и ошибку NameError: name 'сhannel' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

[С документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Guild.get_channel)
И я бы посоветовал использовать `ctx` вместо `message` или же присвоить тип этой перемене

```
async def report(message: discord.ContextType)
```

```
guild = ctx.message.guild
channel = guild.get_channel(821809754061013046)
```

Comment: Это не помогло, до сих пор та же самая ошибка...

Comment: Первый аргумент - всегда типа `discord.Context`, конвертеры на него не применяются.

Comment: @Fixator10, я боялся что могут быть проблеми, например с получением разных данных с `Context`, вот так: `message.message.author.id`, но я посмотрел на его код и понял что ето не мешает